# How do I enable copy/paste between vim and tmux in both two directions?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, os-clipboard, tmux

In a tmux session, I'm running vim in one pane and a terminal in another pane.
Recently, I figured out how to enter *visual mode* in tmux but it doesn't help much now.

Can I yank selected text from a pane and paste it to another (within vim or not), and how can I do this?
The other way, how can I yank some text from vim and paste it to another pane?

Comment: I could have sworn Ive answered something like this before, but I can’t find it. The answer is yes, there are tmux bindings that allow this (and tpope has a plugin, tbone I think, that makes it easy in vim). But if your question is about tmux and not vim, it’s off-topic here.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 1):

Plugin [vim-tmux-clipboard](https://github.com/roxma/vim-tmux-clipboard) seems to be what you're after. It mirrors Vim's unnamed register (default one for yank, delete and put operations) to and from the tmux clipboard.

Make sure you take a close look at the requirements when enabling this plug-in. For Vim, you need at least version 8.0.1394 and you also need plug-in [vim-tmux-focus-events](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/vim-tmux-focus-events) to be enabled. (For NeoVim, there are no additional requirements.)

You also need to enable `set -g focus-events on` on tmux for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to paste to terminal, but you can make the two vim instances share the same clipboard.
First check that if your vim supports clipboard by typing `vim --version`, if you see `+clipboard` in the output, then in your `~/.vimrc`, add

```
set clipboard=unnamed
```

now you can freely yank and paste between tmux panes and windows.

Comment: Note that this also means copying text in other applications changes what will be put by default

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thanks for reminding, that is a little bit tricky...